# Tkinter Text widget: search for anything outside a list

Tags: python, list, search, text, tkinter

In Python Tkinter, how can you put a `search` function to a Text widget so it searches only text outside a given list ?

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

text = Text(root)
text.pack()

def searchForTextOutsideList(event):
    list=["bacon","ham","sandwich"]
    ... # How can I search the text widget for only words not in the list

root.mainloop()
```

How can I search the text widget for only words not in the list. Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of what you want to do exactly. If you only want to get the words not in your list, just use `text.get("1.0","end")` to get the content of the Text widget, then split it in words and check if each word is in your list or not.

Edit: If you want the index of the first letter of each word not in the list you can do something like that

```
def indices(word_list):
    """ return the index of the first letter of each word 
        in the text widget which is not in word_list """
    lines = text.get("1.0", "end").split("\n")
    index = []
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        words = line.split()
        if words:
            if not words[0] in word_list:
                index.append("%i.0" % (i+1))
            for j in range(1, len(words)):
                if not words[j] in word_list:
                    index.append("%i.%i" % (i+1, 1 + len(" ".join(words[:j]))))
    return index
```

I assumed in this function that there is never a white space at the beginning of a line.

Comment: The first index should be `"1.0"`, not `0.0`. Line numbers begin with 1 (one).

Comment: I had never noticed because it doesn't raise an error.

Comment: It doesn't throw an error, but it's still incorrect. Tkinter is a little forgiving of bad indices, but you should still strive to give a proper index whenever possible.

Comment: You are right, I have corrected my post. However, I find strange to start at 1 for the lines and 0 for the columns.

Comment: Strange or not, that's the documented behavior. The canonical documentation is here: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/text.htm#M8

Comment: What if I want to get the index of the words ?

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how to get the index of the words.